# use styled-components to share styles between components/elements

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

I am using styled-components along with Gatsby. I used styled-components to style the `Link` component provided by Gatsby for my home page.

```js
const HomePageLink = styled(Link)`
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: ${fontSizes.xxlarge};
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  :link,
  :visited {
    color: ${colors.slate};
  }
  :hover,
  :active {
    color: ${colors.red};
  }
`
```

However I realize that I also need to style a plain html `<a />` tag using the exactly same style. I  wonder is there a way to make the style component above adapt to `<a />` tags without duplicating the code like this

```js
const HomePageAnchorTag = styled.a`
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: ${fontSizes.xxlarge};
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  :link,
  :visited {
    color: ${colors.slate};
  }
  :hover,
  :active {
    color: ${colors.red};
  }
`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use [`css` API](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css) which allows you to construct reusable CSS blocks.

> A helper function to generate CSS from a template literal with interpolations.

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';
const reusableCSS = css`
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: ${fontSizes.xxlarge};
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  :link,
  :visited {
    color: ${colors.slate};
  }
  :hover,
  :active {
    color: ${colors.red};
  }
`;

const HomePageAnchorTag = styled.a`
  ${reusableCSS}
`;

const HomePageLink = styled(Link)`
  ${reusableCSS}
`;
```

Usually, you will notice a `mixins.js` file that contains exports of reusable `css` block, for example:

```
// mixins.js
const flexCenter = css`...`
export default { flexCenter };

// usage inside styled components.
${mixins.flexCenter}
```